# Is there any way to permanently disable capitalization in Dragon for Mac?

Tags: macos, dragon-naturally-speaking, voice-command

I have been using versions of Dragon/NaturallySpeaking for a decade.  I've just started using Dragon for Mac.

I know how to get specific characters to appear in lowercase, but I do this so often that it significantly slows down my computer use. (I'm a programmer.)

Is there any way to turn off capitalization by default? My dream is that I could say "the alphabet starts with abc and it ends with xyz" and it would write "the alphabet starts with abc and it ends with xyz" instead of "the alphabet starts with ABC and it ends with XYZ".

Currently I would have to say "the alphabet starts with (pause) lowercase abc (pause) and it ends with (pause) lowercase xyz", and even that doesn't work most of the time because of Dragon's weird attempts to interpret this as an an editing command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way that I know of to do that permamently, but there is the built-in editing command "no caps on" and "no caps off".

After saying "no caps on" you can just say things like "seattle is not the capital of the state of washington, olympia is." All characters will appear in lowercase.

That the lowercase mode is activated can be seen in the status window like this:
[image: Status window showing lowercase mode in Dragon for Mac]

Check out the vocabulary editor for more tricks.